# How to delete in use content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, content-type, administration

I have received a request today to hide/delete a site content type. I thought it is an easy task but it's making me sick.

Every time I try to delete the content type I am getting the below error message.

Is there any way I can hide it instead of deleting it?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide it from a single list or complete SharePoint site? You can hide content type in a list easily.

Comment: can you let me know both?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior in SharePoint. If you are using the content type in a list, you cannot delete it directly from site.

First you have to remove the site content type from all lists & then you can delete it from site settings --> Site content types.

---

Alternatively, you can hide the content type from list instead of deleting it. Follow below steps:

1. Go to list settings --> Advanced settings
2. On advanced settings page, set **Allow management of content types** to **Yes** & click **OK** at the bottom of page
3. Then from list settings page, select **Change new button order and default content type** under **Content Types** section.

   [image]
4. Uncheck the content type you want to hide & click **OK**

   [image]

Comment: To top the answer, you need to as well delete the items from recycle bin that were using this content type.